# Good grapher software for modelling

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I am modelling DNA and require a software which can graph equations/functions, parametric equations and data sets in 3D. I have tried Microsoft Mathematics, but it is useless when combining more elements together. Also it would be fantastic if there were the option to control the color of each input. Any suggestions? At this point I am ready to put some cash into it.

Comment: MATLAB is a great resource for this, and you can definitely control colours there.

Comment: Do you think the code language is difficult to learn for that program? I also have a number of equations, do you know if they are easy to input?

Comment: It's fairly easy to learn and equations are pretty easy to type. You might want to look up some videos on YouTube to see what it's like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Graphing Calculator 3D" software for what you need. It plots equations (both explicit and implicit), parametric equations and scatter data sets in 3D. The color of each equation or set of data can be independently changed with single or multiple color gradients. There is no coding necessary.